# Materialize partial set of results with EF Core 2.1

Tags: entity-framework-core, ienumerable, iqueryable, ef-core-2.1

Let's say I have a large collection of tasks stored in DB and I want to retrieve the latest one according to requesting user's permissions. The permissions checking logic is complex and not related to the persistence layer, hence I can't put it in an SQL query. What I'm doing today is retrieving ALL tasks from DB ordered by descending date, then filter them by permissions set and taking first one. Not a perfect solution: I retrieve thousands of objects when I need only one.

My question is: how can I materialize objects coming from DB until I find one that matches my criteria and discards rest of results?

I thought about one solution, but couldn't find information regarding EF Core behavior in this case and don't know how to check it myself:

Build the IQueryable, cast to IEnumerable, then iterate over it and take the first good task. I know that IQueryable part will be executed on Server and IEnumerable on the client, but I don't know if all task will be materialized before applying FilterByPermissions or it will be performed by demand? And I also don't like the synchronous nature of this solution.

```
    IQueryable<MyTask> allTasksQuery = ...;
    IEnumerable<MyTask> allTasksEnumerable = allTasksQuery.AsEnumerable();

    IEnumerable<MyTask> filteredTasks = FilterByPermissions(allTasksEnumerable);
    MyTask latestTask = filteredTasks.FirstOrDefault();
```

The workaround could be retrieving small sets of data (pages of 50 for example) until one good task is found but I don't like it.

Comment: try the similar logic `var items = context.YourEntityClass.Where( x=> permissionSet.Contains(x.permissionId)).OrderByDescending(u => u.dateProperty).Take(1);`

Comment: Currently EF queries are generally *streaming*, i.e. not fully materialized. AFAIK there are ideas to add *buffered* mode, but hopefully it would be *opt-in*. You can easily check that by putting breakpoint or some trace inside `MyTask` constructor.

Comment: @IvanStoev please check my logic and let me know if I understood the question properly and is it solving the issue?

Comment: @IvanStoev I have deleted my anser, because it was not answering his question.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, the breakpoint did the trick :) It really materializes only demanded objects. But does it mean that other objects won't be transferred from the server or they are already sit as a raw data on client side?

Comment: As far as I know, EF queries go through ADO.NET `ExecuteReader`, then create entity from each record returned by the reader. Since both data reader and `IEnumerable` allow streaming (`ReadNext`, `MoveNext`), there should be 1 record / 1 entity at the time. Of course the data reader might receive data in chinks bigger than 1 record, but in general this is the relatively safe assumption.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you. If you will write it as an answer I'll accept it.